# How to log a multiline run command in GitHub Actions workflows

Tags: logging, github-actions

I find GH's log outputs quite incomplete. This is how I am logging my shell commands at the moment:

```yaml
      - name: Run stuff
        run: |
          mkdir log
          touch log/log.txt
          echo "init... "  &>> log/log.txt
          echo "\$cmd1"  &>> log/log.txt
          cmd1  &>> log/log.txt
          echo "\$cmd2"  &>> log/log.txt
          cmd2  &>> log/log.txt
```

I then upload the `log` folder as artefact. I'm hoping there's a more efficient way to log such steps. Maybe an action that takes a command list and logs it. I know I can save this as an exec file and run+log it in one go, but I was hoping I won't have to commit this into my repo and clutter the commit history.

Comment: You want to log all output that the step had produced?